# Reduction Algorithm for Dot Product of Two 1D Vectors

Tags: cuda

I've been trying to work out an algorithm to get the dot product of two vectors within a CUDA program via reduction and seem to be stuck :/

In essence, I'm trying to write this code in CUDA:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    h_h += h_a[i] * h_b[i];
```

Where `h_a` and `h_b` are arrays of floats and `h_h` sums up the dot product.

I'm trying to use reduction here - so far I've got this...

```
__global__ void dot_product(int n, float * d_a, float * d_b){

     int i = threadIdx.x;

     for (int stride = 1; i + stride < n; stride <<= 1) {
         if (i % (2 * stride) == 0){
             d_a[i] += d_a[i + stride] * d_b[i + stride];
         }
         __syncthreads();
     }
}
```

If I change the main line to `d_a[i] += d_a[i + stride];`, it sums up the array just fine. I seem to be running into a parallel issue here from what I gather. Can someone point out my issue?

My kernel call is:

`dot_product<<<1, n>>>(n, d_a, d_b);`, where `n` is the size of each array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. As pointed out in comments, you never calculate the product of the first elements (this is a minor issue)
2. Your dot product calculation is incorrect. The parallel reduction should be performing a sum of the individual products of corresponding elements. Your code performs the product at every stage of the parallel reduction, so that products are getting multiplied again as they as are summed. That is incorrect.

You want to do something like this:

```
__global__ void dot_product(int n, float * d_a, float * d_b){

     int i = threadIdx.x;

     d_a[i] = d_a[i] * d_b[i]; // d_a now contains products
     __syncthreads();

     for (int stride = 1; i + stride < n; stride <<= 1) {
         if (i % (2 * stride) == 0){
             d_a[i] += d_a[i + stride]; // which are summed by reduction
         }
         __syncthreads();
     }
}
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled or test, use at own risk]